# Auctex previews

Tags: math-mode, pstricks, auctex

I am using PSTricks and trying to generate an inline preview with auctex for part of a document.

This works fine if I surround the whole thing in `$` signs like

```
$
\begin{pspicture}
...
\end{pspicture}
$
```

but this doesn't work when I want to use a math variable, say `$\theta$` within that block. I expected using `\theta` without the dollar signs would work, but it doesn't.

Is there a way to generate inline previews without surrounding dollar signs, or is there a way to include nested dollar signs within the section?

Comment: pspicture will make a box so you will need $ to get back into math mode, just as `$ ++ \mbox{text $math$ text} +++$`

Comment: @David Carlisle nesting dollar signs throws off auctex preview though. Any way around that?

Comment: looks like instead of wrapping pspicture in a spurious $ you should just add pspicture to the environments preview-latex knows about: gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/preview-latex/… has a section _Preview your favourite LaTeX constructs _

Comment: yes, that works

Answer (score 3):

Instead of wrapping `pspicture` in a spurious `$` you should just add `pspicture` to the environments preview-latex knows about: http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/preview-latex/Simple-customization.html has a section *Preview your favourite LaTeX constructs* with details of tehe customisation required.